# Rails: How do I search tags generated by Act_As_Taggable_On with PG_Search? (postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, search, pg-search

I am currently using [Act_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) for tagging and [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) to search through my postgresql database on my Rails 3 application.

How would I search through tags generated by the act_as_taggable_on gem with pg_search? I can view the tags of a Post by saying "Post.find(1).tag_list," but there are no "tag" columns in the Post table, so when I run the

```
 pg_search_scope :search_by_weight, :against => {:tag_list => 'A', :title => 'B', :content => 'C'} #,:using => [:tsearch => {:prefix => true}] #:trigram, :dmetaphone]
```

it gives me an error because the column Post.tag_list doesn't exist in the Post table. What is it called when you can find the value through the dot connector (i.e. mission.tag_list) but when it doesn't exist in the table? I didn't know what to type. So basically, how do I pass in a non-existent column as a params?

Also, you may have noticed I commented out the

```
 :using => [:tsearch => {:prefix => true}] #:trigram, :dmetaphone]
```

above. I can't seem to find how to install extra modules for Postgresql. Where do I type CREATE EXTENSION? (using ubuntu 11.10 and postgresql 9.1.3 -> and heroku for production)

Comment: @muistooshort any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A much more simple approach is just using the association and search that through pg_search which is done like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 include PgSearch  

  pg_search_scope :full_search, 
    :against => {  
    :item_status => 'A',
    :title => 'B',
    :description => 'C'    
   },       
    :associated_against => {
    :tags => [:name]    
   }
end
```

I just implemented this in one of my projects and it worked well (searched through tag names).  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to weight an associated relationship since it says "tags" column not found in Items table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah I actually figured it out to this point so far, but I had the same problem weighing the tags as well. 

Were you able to get the additional search features (ie trigram) to work? (Are you using Heroku?)

Comment: Hi, I didn't try adding any other additional search features, just the association one.  I am using Heroku and unfortunately the pg_search gem isn't working for me right now but I am working on it.  Supposedly pg_search is easy to use with Heroku unlike some other full text search engines so I am thinking it will be an easy fix.  Still would be great if tags could be weighted or if tags could be done with an "exact match" otherwise what is the purpose of tags?

Comment: I see. Yeah I think I got the extra features to work locally, but I don't think it works on Heroku right now. (I think it might be because I need to update or install the contrib packages on the server, but heroku won't let me access the updating and installing of the pg database)

Comment: I guess I'll just have to be satisfied with it not giving me an error.

Comment: Any idea how I would order the search results by "karma"(votes)? 
I got rid of the weights and did:
@missions = Mission.search_by_weight(params[:query]).order("karma desc").page(params[:page]).per(12) // but it still lists it by relevance(weight)

Comment: For weights on tag try use `tags: { name: 'A' }` - or 'B','C','D'

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to get the tags weighted as well

```
    pg_search_scope :search_by_weight, 
      :against => {  
      :title => 'B',
      :content => 'C'    
    },       
    :associated_against => {
      :tags => { :name => 'A' }    
    },
    using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "english"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my implementation in plpgsql a few years ago. See my blog: http://omarqureshi.net/articles/2010-12-25-tsearch2-for-rails-applications which covers how to get it working.

Comment: Hm... as a beginner, it is still really confusing to try to understand what you are doing in your blog post and apply it to my situation..

Comment: I would start off by reading a guide on plpgsql and the trigger documentation for postgres.

Comment: This is the solution! Very good post Omar, though some functions are a bit overcomplicated and I cleaned them a bit. Nevertheless I would have never made it without your blog post. I would vote you up by 10 points if I could :) cheers